# Change Intellij's maven archetype plugin version when creating a project

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, maven

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5.

I have also installed the maven 3.5.0 on my computer, because it supports maven-archetype-plugin 3.0.1. I need this version because older versions miss certain features that I need to use.

I am able to use maven-archetype-plugin 3.0.1 from the command line and (after configuring the maven projects window to use maven 3.5.0) by making it execute the goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (in stead of normally doing archetype:generate, which defaults to maven-archetype-plugin 2.3)

So now my questions.

First of all, how can I configure IntelliJ to use version 3.0.1 in stead of 2.3 when doing **File** | **New** | **Project...** and selecting maven to create a new project? I can't find a way to configure it to use v3.0.1

Second of all, is there a way to make version 3.0.1 the default so that from the command line I can just use archetype:generate in stead of the full name of the plugin?